# Will Calcium Carbonate react with Sodium Chloride?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

After reading through my school chemistry notes and the answer to the question here at Chem S.E of how do we know whether an $\ce{A + B}$ reaction will occur, I find myself stuck on this very basic question. 
I understand that $\ce{CaCO3 + HCl}$ will react as it is an acid + base reaction and that the reverse reaction $\ce{Na2CO3 + CaCl2}$ to $\ce{CaCO3}$ and $\ce{HCl}$ is possible. 
I don't think I can use bond enthalpy to figure out if the reaction is spontaneous or non-spontaneous, because the reactants and products are ionic rather than molecular compounds. 
I believe that I might need to use some sort of enthalpy calculation to figure this reaction out, but I'm not sure which specific one in particular. 
On a whim, I believe that this reaction will not occur but I'm still very uncertain.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. I suggest that you take the short [tour] to further familiarize yourself with how this site works. As this reads like a homework-type of question (though I could be wrong) you should also read through [this](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142) discussion. To get you started, do you think it would react? Why or why not? Showing some work and effort on your part will motivate others to invest their time and effort in helping you. Good luck!

Comment: [Well the reverse is true.](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-39)